# How to upload a file to AL11 with SAPUI5 and AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, sapui5

### Environment:

Framework: SAPUI5
IDE: SAP web ide

### Code tested:

```
_uploadCss: function (oCss) {
            var that = this;
            var i18n = this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle();
            var oComunicate = this.getView().byId("ComArea");
            var sOrigin = location.origin.includes("webidetesting") ? "https://" + "gtyext.net" : location.origin;
            var sUploadUrl = sOrigin + "/sap/public/files/"; //AL11 URL
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("style.css", oCss);
            $.ajax({
                url: sUploadUrl,
                method: "POST",
                data: formData,
                headers: {"x-csrf-token": that.getOwnerComponent().getModel("authorisation").getSecurityToken()},
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            }).done(function(oRes){
                let oMessageStrip = new MessageStrip({
                        text: i18n.getText("CssFileSentToServer"),
                        customIcon: "sap-icon://complete",
                        type: "Success",
                        showIcon: true,
                        showCloseButton: true
                    });
                    oComunicate.addItem(oMessageStrip);
            }).fail(function(oErr){
                let oMessageStrip = new MessageStrip({
                        text: i18n.getText("CssFileNotSent",[oErr.status]),
                        customIcon: "sap-icon://error",
                        type: "Error",
                        showIcon: true,
                        showCloseButton: true
                    });
                    oComunicate.addItem(oMessageStrip);
            });
},
```

Where oCss is a blob file for example :

```
var sCSSCode =
                `.sapMShellGlobalOuterBackground {
                    background-image: none;
                    background-color: white;
                }
                .contentBackground{
                    background-image: none;
                    background-color: white;
                }
                .integratedPage{
                    height: 350px;
                }`;
var oCss = new Blob([sCSSCode], {
    type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
});
```

### Response from the web console:

> abap.js:2 POST https://gtyext.net/sap/public/files/ 404 (Not found)

### If I copy the URL to the browser :

in browser https://gtyext.net/sap/public/files/
[image: Screenshot of 403]

### Problems:

How can I upload the file?
Why do I get 404 not found in the console (from post request) and 403 in browser (so GET request)?

Comment: I think you get 403 in the browser because the address bar is always GET.  You can do POST requests only via JS or with some external tool. I can recommend Insomnia REST Client where you can simulate your request. Why doesn't it work in your WebIDE then? Maybe it's a CORS error? Have you added your API as a destination?

Comment: With sap gateway when I simulate post I also get 404 so post give 404 and get 403, the 403 is expected but the 404 no. The reslt is the same once deployed on the same domain. A solution we found now is to post to an entityset who will upload to AL11.